# Removing composite PK and adding new index is incredibly slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, composite-primary-key

I currently have a composite PK (clustered) consisting of 3 columns, let's call them A, B and C, all needed to ensure uniqueness. Due to external factors I need to modify this table by removing the current PK and adding a new index on a new column instead.

This is done by a standard

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Name

CREATE INDEX Index_Name ON Table_Name (NewColumn)
```

The problem is that the table is huge (some 70 million rows) and performing a drop on the current PK and then adding the new index takes over an hour. Is there any way to fix the situation in a more performance efficient way?

The table only has its composite PK, so no NCIs or FKs and other dependencies to worry about. I am working on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is the exact table definition? How big is the table in terms of numbers of pages? Does the transaction log have plenty of free space?  What auto growth settings do you have on your files?

Comment: @MartinSmith, autoGrowth is set to 10% for the table files and 100 MB for the table log file. There is plenty of room left in the log file since the restriction is set high. The table size is 16803216 KB originally, the index taking up 52288 KB.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to create a new table with the right constraints.  Then you copy over all the rows.  At the end, you drop the old table, and `sp_rename` the new one.  The rename is fast and that reduces downtime.

You might have to put some thought into rows that are being added during the copy operation.  One way to deal with that is to rename to old table, and then copy any new rows over, and only after that rename the new table.  This still results in a much shorter downtime than an altering the table in-place.

Comment: I will look into this and test run a script in my test environment to check execution time.

Comment: Copying the rows over to a new table with the right setup has been running for over one hour now and is still not done, so unfortunately this does not seem to be an option.

Comment: Well, the idea is not that it runs quicker, but that it reduces downtime.  The clients are only affected during the drop + rename, which completes in under a second.